# Can we find a word in a song using python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am new to python.
I want to find if a word is part of a song

For example,

if i have a rhyme "johnny johnny yes papa, eating sugar no papa" as an mp3 or wav file.

I will give the word "sugar" and time as 0 to 5 seconds as input.
Is it possible to check if sugar word comes in the given 5 seconds?

Kindly help me with this.

Thanks,
Shobha

Answer (score 1):

Not without a lot of work on your part.

Most speech recognition algorithms are tuned for normal speech, not singing. Recognizing words in a song is much more difficult (even for humans!), and algorithms to do so are still highly experimental. ([A research project in 2010](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/224150170_Recognition_of_phonemes_and_words_in_singing) was only able to recognize 39% of words correctly in an unaccompanied song, for example; recognition rates dropped even further for singing with musical accompaniment.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.